# What does the Japanese onomatopoeia もきゅもきゅ mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, onomatopoeia

I heard this in a Japanese song sung by Vocaloid Hatsune Miku ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkYbNnGe2Ik))

Does anyone know what this onomatopoeia means? It's clear from the context of the lyrics that it is an onomatopoeia, but I've never heard it used before.

For context, the lyrics say:

> ホッペタを少し膨らませて
>   I’ll puff out my cheeks and go
>
> モキュモキュにしてやるぞ
>   “mokyu mokyu” just for you, OK?
>
> アヒルみたいな唇をして
>   I’ll make duck lips and go
>
> モキュモキュにしてやるぞ
>   “mokyu mokyu” just for you, OK！

Comment: http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%82%E3%81%8D%E3%82%85%E3%82%82%E3%81%8D%E3%82%85

Comment: Just so you know, it's not an official word, but one that was made up.  It's used because it's cute sounding.

Answer (score 3):

It means "cute (and fluffy)".

Imagine a hamster stuffing its face with food.

Answer (score 1):

earthliŋ's response has a link to a Japanese page that explains the meaning but for those who can't read Japanese I figured I'd answer in English.

It basically means cute in a soft and cuddly way.